# Unravel the \writecontentsline mystery

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, titletoc, minitoc, beamerarticle

Trying to program a macro that is similar to `\adcontentsline`: Applying  `\immediate\write` to, say ,

```
\frameEntry{\insertframenumber}{\inserframetitle \}{\thepage}
```

records the wrong page number. Conversely, if the `\write` is postponed to the time the page is shipped, then the wrong `\insertpagenumber` and the wrong `\insertpagetitle` are recorded.

More context: I work on writing my own little set of macros for table of contents., with the purpose of generating an edition of set of some hundreds of slides in `article` mode.  The challenge is to produce a list of frames in the style of table of contents, right after each `\subsection`.

Packages such as `minitoc` and `titletoc` did not work. The former since it refuses to produce a table of contents and the latter because it does not play well with `hyperref`.

Comment: you should be able to use `\protected@write` that expands everything _except_ `\thepage` at the point of use and `\thepage` as the page is shipped out.

Comment: have you tried [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) ?

Comment: Not really. That is to say, I tried reading the manual, more than once. Could not really figure how I should use the package. I would appreciate help in doing it.

Comment: apologies about my misguided advice, I completely overlooked your  `beamer` tag and  mentions of frames. The `beamer` class completely rewrites the format of the `.toc` file, hence [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) is incompatible with this class.

Comment: however, using it with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}` is possible. Is this what you mean? a `mwe` would have helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) is incompatible with the `beamer` class.

However, if `beamer` is used in an `article` mode, i.e.,  with the `article` class and the `beamerarticle` package, then `etoc` is applicable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{etoc}
% section=1, subsection=2, subsubsection=3
\etocsetlevel {beamerframe}{6}% dummy, a priori invisible, level
\etocsettocdepth {all}

% Earlier provisory code by jfbu
% \let\oldframetitle \frametitle
% \renewcommand\frametitle [1]{%
%              \etoctoccontentsline{beamerframe}{#1}%
%              \oldframetitle {#1}%
% }
%%%%

% Better code by Yossi Gil
% Override action when frame title is encountered:
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
   \paragraph{\insertframenumber.~\insertframetitle}\\
   \noindent\emph{\insertframesubtitle}\par
   \etoctoccontentsline{beamerframe}{\insertframenumber.~\insertframetitle}%
} 
%%%%

% Command to list frames in a sub-section:
\newcommand\listofframesinsubsection {\begingroup
  % we are going to list one frame per line, with dots up to the page number,
  % this is the default etoc design for subsections, we thus need to set the
  % level of a beamerframe to 2. But then we need to artificially move up the
  % leve of subsection so that \localtableofcontents does see the beamerframes
  % as sub levels of a subsection
    \etocsetlevel {subsection}{1}% artificially pretending subsections are
                                % sections  one up the level
    \etocsetlevel {beamerframe}{2}% pretending beamerframes are subsections
    \etoctoclines % use the styles defined by \etocsetstyle, or here, as we
                  % didn't make any use of \etocsetstyle, just defaults
                  % to the package default styles (which are convenient for
                  % us here.)
    \etocsettocstyle {\noindent Frames in this subsection:\par}{}%
    \etocsetnexttocdepth {beamerframe}%
    \localtableofcontents
\endgroup % clean up all our mess for the next \localtableofcontents  not to
          % be affected and proceed in compatibility mode with the same
          % default design as in article class
}

\begin{document}

\etocsetnexttocdepth {subsection}
\tableofcontents

  \section{Some frames}

%\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Local contents:}}{}
\etocsettocstyle {}{}
\etocsetnexttocdepth {subsection}
 \localtableofcontents 

\subsection {first subsection}
\listofframesinsubsection

\begin{frame}\frametitle{AHK}
  Ah Ah 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{AHJ}
  Oh Oh
\end{frame}

\subsection {second subsection}
\listofframesinsubsection

\begin{frame}\frametitle{HBZ}
  Ah Ah 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{HBW}
  Oh Oh
\end{frame}

  \section{More frames}

%\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Local contents:}}{}
\etocsettocstyle {}{}
\etocsetnexttocdepth {subsection}
 \localtableofcontents 


\subsection {third subsection}
\listofframesinsubsection

\begin{frame}\frametitle{BHK}
  Ah Ah 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{BHJ}
  Oh Oh
\end{frame}

\subsection {fourth subsection}
\listofframesinsubsection


\begin{frame}\frametitle{BBZ}
  Ah Ah 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{BBW}
  Oh Oh
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(the images have been re-generated to reflect the insertion of the frame number added in updated code)

Note: in the code above, the frames declare a paragraph; if the only paragraphs encountered in the subsections are associated in such a way with frames, it is possible to simplify the preamble, there is no need to define a `beamerframe` sectioning level for `etoc`. Here is such a streamlined preamble (if the document has already been compiled with the earlier preamble, one should trash the auxiliary files, or just compile twice, ignoring error on first compilation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{etoc}
% section=1, subsection=2, subsubsection=3
\etocsettocdepth {all}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
   \paragraph{\insertframenumber.~\insertframetitle}\\
   \noindent\emph{\insertframesubtitle}\par
} 

% Command to list frames in a sub-section:
\newcommand\listofframesinsubsection {\begingroup
    \etocsetlevel {subsection}{1}% pretending subsections are sections
    \etocsetlevel {paragraph}{2}% pretending paragraphs are subsections
    \etoctoclines % allows to use the package default styles for subsections
    \etocsettocstyle {\noindent Frames in this subsection:\par}{}%
    \etocsetnexttocdepth {paragraph}%
    \localtableofcontents
\endgroup 
}
```

[image: etoc with beamerarticle page 1]
[image: etoc with beamerarticle page 2]

---

[YG:]

The above commands will not work in any mode other than `article`. For this reason
it is probably best to protect the above in `\mode{`most of the above preamble`}`.

Another best practice is to use two separate containing files, for the article and the slides mode. Both this files should `\input` the files where the actual frames are. If this is what you do, then there is no need for such a protection.

Comment: I think it is better to encapsulate the commands in `\mode<article>{...}`. Also,  `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \paragraph{\insertframenumber.~\insertframetitle}\\
    \noindent\emph{\insertframesubtitle}\par
    \etoctoccontentsline{frame}{\insertframenumber.~\insertframetitle}%
  }` might be slightly better than overriding `\frametitle`.

Comment: sadly I am quite ignorant in beamer matters as you realized from my slow understanding that `beamer in article mode` meant `beamerarticle package in another class than beamer`. I find this wording in the `beamer` manual quite disputable, if we are in article class, we are in article class, not beamer class (hence my `etoc is not compatible with beamer class` which you have edited). Please do edit further if you feel like it my answer (explaining it is your addition), adding at the end the correct formulation. I patched `\frametitle` from lack of knowledge, I am glad there is a better way.

Comment: Would it be OK if I edit your answer to reflect the changes I suggest?

Comment: @YossiGil absolutely OK, please do.

Comment: @YossiGil I pay attention to it only now, but your code allows to drop entirely my `\etoctoccontentsline` thing. Indeed, your  `\frametitle` does a paragraph. These go to the toc file. Thus, replace `beamerframe` by `paragraph` in the command `\listofframesinsubsection`, suppress the `\etoctoccontentsline` thing and the `\etocsetlevel{beamerframe}{6}` and it will all work.